# Batch script to echo the current task from a 'for' variable list

Tags: windows, windows-7, batch-file, windows-xp

I'm running a batch script that calls the binary NiniteOneTrial to install a bunch of apps listed in the "applist.txt".  This works great, but I want to see if there is a way to setup a variable that prints to the screen (echo) the app that is currently being installed (per the applist.txt calls):

Basically, want to replace the %%CURRENTTASKFROMLIST%% with the app currently being installed from that list.

```
set CACHEPATH=\\server-01\local_apps\Ninite\netcache
set file_list=C:/ninite/applist.txt

:appinstall
for /f %%1 in (%file_list%) do (
  echo . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . [ Installing %%CURRENTTASKFROMLIST%% ]
  cmd /c C:/ninite/NiniteOneTrial.exe /disableautoupdate /disableshortcuts /allusers /select %%1 /silent . /cachepath %CACHEPATH%
)
```

Comment: I'm confused. What is it that you want to echo? I.e., what is CURRENTTASKFROMLIST supposed to be? Do you want to echo something different from the `%%1` you are using on the next line?

Comment: The applist.txt file has a list of applications.  The :appinstall segment calls each item on that list.  I get the echo: "Installing xxx" for every single item that is ran, but I want to make it so the 'xxx' a certain variable that actually tells me which item is being ran at the time.  Sorry, I'm a newbie programmer and my terminology is still pretty green :)

Comment: I'm still not sure what you're trying to print. Suppose file_list contains the line "app1". Do you want to print "Installing app1"? If so, then just use `%%1` like you're doing on the next line.

Comment: I thought I had tried that :|, did it again and viola!.  Thanks!

Comment: Excuse me. Your Batch file run just by chance. All known documentation said that `FOR` replaceable parameters must be a **LETTER** (uppercase or lowercase) because the %-digit pair is reserved for the Batch file parameters. Although the %-digit also works in `FOR` (just made a test), this behaviour is completely undocumented! For example `for %%1 in (%1) do echo %%1` works in a Batch file, but `for %1 in (%1) do echo %1` in the command-line also works with nonsense result. PLEASE, don't use %-digit in `FOR`, change it for %-letter! :)

Comment: @Aacini Thanks for the feedback.  Read more about it and you're right, I went ahead and changed it to a letter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your question and comments it sounds like you want to just use `%%1` where you have `%%CURRENTTASKFROMLIST%%`. The `%%1` in the for loop will provide you with the app name that is currently being installed.